# Show index along with filtered results to stdout

Tags: git, shell, sh

I have a script that searches git repositories for text as a sh command that I can pipe into other custom search methods. It's similar in idea to `git log -S` but being much more extensible and still pretty quick.

Here's the WIP script

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh

ROOT=`git rev-parse --show-toplevel`

# Explanation:
#
# Git uses pack (*.idx) files to compress older commits. One line reads this
# file and uncompresses it to get the original git indices.
#
# The second command reads the more recent git indices, as-is.
#
find $ROOT/.git/objects/pack -name "*.idx" | xargs -I{} sh -c 'git show-index < "{}"' | awk '{print $2}' | git -C $ROOT cat-file --batch
find $ROOT/.git/objects/ -type f | grep -v '/pack/\|/info/packs$' | awk -F'/' '{print $(NF-1)$NF}' | git -C $ROOT cat-file --batch
```

So to use it, you'd save it to a file like `git-searcher` and then go `git-searcher | grep -a "def get_foo"` to get all functions starting with "get_foo". Or you can do more complex queries, such as "get me URLs that contain both "http" and "foo" in its name

`git-searcher | sed -e '/http/!d -e '/foo/!d'`

Here's my question.

I would like to modify this script to show the indices of search results along with the filtered content. Is that possible to do, while still keeping the query fast? I use this on a very big git repository, so speed is important.

Ideally I'd like a call like this

`git-searcher | grep -a "foo"` to output text like

```
ff7c1dfa2447eae0c3d51b8ddea3e4a6ff32acf
    def __init__(self):
    def __call__(self, match):
ff7e497f3b1884e2934e37914da497f2ece9c7a9
...
```

Or something similar so I know which indices created which match(es)

Comment: I don't understand what your tool is doing exactly. It's printing all the commits? How does it differ from `git log -S`? I believe that traversing via `.git/objects` files manually is a bad idea.

Comment: It differs only in that you can customize how you search for things. If you have more complex queries that you want to do, `git log -S` isn't enough. But if you're just doing a partial match, `git log -S` works.

Comment: What do you mean by complex queries? I see `git log` supports all the `grep` things, including perl regexp. I also see your tool output is not affected by the expression used, so what does your `git-searcher` outputs? `get me URLs that contain both "http" and "foo" in its name` like `git log --grep 'http.*foo'` or `git log --all-match --grep foo --grep http`?